# Get-Childitem Workaround

Tags: powershell, path, max, robocopy, get-childitem

I want to determine which files/filetypes consume most space on the fileserver. Due to the fact that alot of users created files with a name/path length over 260 char gci does not work.(shortcuts-in-shortcuts-in-shortcuts-infinity)

My next step was to create a workaround by using something that displays, size file name and path without max_path var limitation.(ROBOCOPY)

Here is my function:

```
Function Get-RoboFileSize($source_name){

$filelog=robocopy.exe /e /l /njh /njs /ndl /fp /nc /bytes $source_name $env:Temp

foreach ($item in $filelog){

   if ($item -like "*$source_name*"){   

         $base=$item -Replace "[\s]",""
         $Filename=$base -Replace "^[0-9]{1,}",""
         $Filesize=$base -Replace "[^\d][a-zA-Z0-9~@#\^\$&\*\(\)-_\+=\[\]\{\}\|\\,\.\?\!\%\§öäüÖÄÜßáàÃ°Þ]{1,}",""

         New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                            Filename=$Filename
                                            FileSize= ("{0:#}" -f($Filesize/1MB))

         }              
    }

}
```

}

This approach works but my problem is that it consumes alot of resources.

Does someone has an idea how to improve this function....maybe an idea for another workaround?

Comment: Are you running Windows 2008R2? If you are, try File Services Resource Manager's reports.

Comment: It want to evaluate this on multiple severs with diffrent os (2003, 2003 R2, 2008, 2008 R2) and schedule a script which sends and a summary with the 100 biggest from each server

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft knows about [path length limitations](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/276235/path-length-limitations).

There is an article that provides a workaround in C#. If you really care about performance, this is your best bet: [Long Paths in .NET, Part 1 of 3 [Kim Hamilton]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx)

If you want to stick with Powershell, see another workaround on [powershell.com forums](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/10114.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I'll test it. Here is the article I read to get to my approach with robocopy. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12179.net-powershell-path-too-long-exception-and-a-net-powershell-robocopy-clone-en-us.aspx